# How to force math symbols up and down inline text

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

I've a simple question I can't figure out.
There should be an option that can force the symbols up and down of a formula put inside text.
e.g. If I write

```
blablabla $\bigcup_{stuff}$ blablabla
```

the part "stuff" is put on the right side of the symbol instead of down. I would like to force "stuff" to be put under the simbol `\bigcup`. What do I have to do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: There's a reason why in inline math limits are not set under the operator (`\bigcup`, `\sum` or similar): the line becomes too high (or deep) and the page is spoiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\limits`:

```
$\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{n}$
```

The above `^` and below `_` parts may be empty, of course. This works also for `\prod` and `\sum`, for example (for all math operators to be exact).

But as mentioned already in the comments: It's not always good to force some output, because the line height could get to big. You have to try with your document because we don't know your settings (font, font size, line height, etc).

Comment: Alternatively: `$\displaystyle \bigcup_{stuff}$`.

Comment: @Jubobs -- using `\displaystyle`, the `\bigcup` will be the full display size.  the text baselines will be quite uneven just using `\limits`; `\displaystyle` will only make the situation worse.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right. Apologies.